# Cheats on Xbox 360 portal 2

Tags: xbox-360, portal-2

Are there cheats on Xbox 360 for Portal 2? I searched and searched for cheat codes for Portal 2 on Xbox 360 but the only thing that pops up is console commands for the pc version. Are there cheats on it or a way to open console on Xbox 360 without mods?

Answer (score 3):

No, this isn't possible to do on the Xbox 360.